# Modifying the ruby on the rails interpreter logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm fairly new to rails, and I'm currently starting on a project that would require me to modify the logic of rails interpreter. This is what I want to do:

Every time a user includes a JavaScript library in rails, I want to perform some operations with this library.

This would require me to:

1. intercept the javascript_include_tag, and hook my function on top of this and,
2. identify all locations where a javascript library is included without using the javascript_include_tag function(maybe after the client side page is generated), and perform some actions on these libraries.

Since I'm new to rails and ruby in general, I have no idea what's the best way to approach this problem. Should I make a plugin? A gem? Or should I modify the interpreter directly?

Comment: Check out custom Rails helpers : http://railscasts.com/episodes/64-custom-helper-modules  . It sounds like you don't need anything complicated enough for a plugin or a gem. Just a few hook/methods .

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is to leave `javascript_include_tag` unmodified, even if you are freely able to [monkey patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) it yourself, and instead serve the JavaScript dynamically.

There are a number of ways to go about doing this, but you can make a `.erb.js` file to respond to an arbitrary action.

Comment: sorry, I'm still confused. How can you use js.erb to find all included javascript libraries?

Comment: There's no way to know this information because calls can be made to `javascript_include_tag` at any time with any arguments, so you'd have to exercise every page under every conceivable arrangement of parameters in order to trigger them all, something that's impractical by definition. Instead of a retrospective approach, you need one that's more declarative. Try creating your own system for defining where JavaScript files are included, like a config file or small DSL, and feed parameters in to `javascript_include_tag` instead of waiting for it to be called.